# iOS: Default Battery Percentage Level for individual services to switch off

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, battery, bluetooth

We all know iOS switches off services one by one when the battery reaches critical level. But is there any fixed battery level to cut down individual services. For example, Bluetooth will be switched off at 20%, Mobile data at 15%, Wifi at 10%, etc. I am searching these in iOS documentation and Googling as well. But I am not able to find such info. Any help please.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing. Do you have any sources, such as an Apple KB article, that say that iOS turns of services when the battery is low?

Comment: Hi Andrew, that is what my question is. If anybody has the sources, it would be helpful. I know in Android, when battery level comes down to 10, the brightness is set to minimum. No services will be shut down until the battery completely drains out. I am looking for some reliable sources for iOS.

Comment: On iOS, services don't automatically turn off until the device runs completely out of battery (and at that point the device is shutting down).